# Trying to wait until iFrame is loaded; $.onload and other methods not working

Tags: iframe, window, load, wait, onload

I have a page with an iFrame. In my javascript, I open a new window in my iFrame, and then direct the user to a new page. This is part of a login process; the iFrame is invisible (or will be, I have it visible for now so that I can see when it's loaded) and loads a URL that logs the user into the site's store, and the user is then redirected back to another page on the site itself (whichever page they came to the login from). It works so long as the iFrame finishes loading before the user is redirected. Here is my iFrame code:

```
<iframe id="ShopifyiFrame" name="ShopifyLogin" src="mysite.org" style="width:500px;height:500px;border:1px solid red" ></iframe>
```

So far though I'm unable to detect when the iFrame has finished loading. I replaced window.location with a simple alert so that I can see when it's triggering. I've tried every method I can find:

Adding an event listener

```
var w = window.open(response.ShopifyMultiPassLoginUrl, "ShopifyLogin");
w.addEventListener("load", alert("iFrame loaded");, true);
```

Using $.when.then

```
$.when(window.open(response.ShopifyMultiPassLoginUrl, "ShopifyLogin")).then(function() {
    alert("iFrame loaded");
});
```

Using .onload

```
$("#ShopifyiFrame").onload = function () {
    alert("iFrame loaded");
}
```

Using .ready

```
$("#ShopifyiFrame").ready(function() {
    alert("iFrame loaded");
});
```

In every case, the alert triggers immediately, even though the page has not loaded in the iFrame yet. Why isn't it waiting, and what do I need to change?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
$('#ShopifyiFrame document').ready(function() {
    alert('loaded');
});
```

$.ready is attached to the document, hence attaching $.ready to iframe's document.